# How to add PDF in Website (Readable Only)

Tags: javascript, html, web

How to add pdf in website for only readable purpose, nobody can download that pdf.

I add .pdf in website by this method

```
<a href="MyPdf.pdf">My PDF</a>
```

but in browser it open this file but also give the option of save as or for download, but i want that when i click on this my user only read this file.

Comment: When you add a PDF to a page the browser loads the complete PDF file. Of course the user can download it then. There is no possibility to prevent that when you serve a PDF.

Comment: what you see is what you get :D

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to prevent the user from downloading and saving the pdf to his/her computer.

If there is a way to do this, the user could still just print screen. There is no way to prevent the user from getting the information if it is available.

Comment: mmm yes, the user can extract absolutely everything from a webpage, absolutely